# Angular directive not working in ionic.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have some troubles to get my directive to load in my ionic.js web app using angular.
I can pass the variable `{{someTitle}}` from the controller to the template, however the directive does not get loaded, i.e. `<div class="blaha" ng-transclude>abc123</div>` does not get passed to the template... Am I missing something fatal below:

Ionic template:

```
<ion-view title="Roll the Dice">
  <ion-content has-tabs="true">
      <div my-dice>{{someTitle}}</div>

      <div class="card">
          <div class="item item-text-wrap">
              {{someTitle}}
          </div>
      </div>


      <button class="button button-dark button-full button-positive">
          Full Width Block Button
      </button>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Controller code:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('TrueDice.controllers', [])


// A simple controller that fetches a list of data from a service
.controller('HistoryIndexCtrl', function($scope, TrueRandomService) {

        if($scope.rands="undefined"){
            $scope.rands = [];
        }
        TrueRandomService.getRand(1).success(function(data){
            $scope.rands.unshift(data);
            console.log(data);
        });
})
.controller('HistoryDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, TrueRandomService) {
  //currently empty

}).controller('RollViewCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.someTitle="BLA";

}).directive('my-dice', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div class="blaha" ng-transclude>abc123</div>',
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            scope: {},
            controller: function($scope, $element) {
               //currently empty
            }
        }
    }]);
```

[image: NotWorking]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `-` from directive name:

```
directive('myDice', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
```

and according to `restrict: 'E'`, you should place **element** in html:

```
<my-dice>{{someTitle}}</my-dice>
```

[example](http://plnkr.co/edit/1bXCBAnYhFFKUo7ATA7q?p=preview)